# Can I insert multiple rows for self-referencing table at same time when inserted rows reference each other?

Tags: sql-server, self-referencing-table

I've got a self-referencing table that has a nullable, unique FK column referencing the PK for another row in the same table. This forms a linked list structure.

I've got all of my various interactions working, including insertions -- just go backward with the first item inserted being the last item in the linked list and each following insert referencing the row number prior.

However, I don't love having to do multiple inserts to handle this. Is there any way to do a multi-row insert where each row being inserted uses the `@@IDENTITY` of the previous row?

I wondered about something like this, but `@@IDENTITY` just returns `null` for all of the next values.

```
INSERT INTO LINKED_LIST (next)
SELECT @@IDENTITY
UNION ALL
SELECT @@IDENTITY
UNION ALL
SELECT @@IDENTITY
```

Reading [the MSDN documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187342.aspx), it makes sense that this doesn't work since the value is not set until after the `INSERT` returns, but the question is whether there is some clever way to achieve the same goal in another way?

Comment: What version of sql server do you have? 2008 - 2012 -2014 ???

Comment: This needs to be supported for `2012` and `2014`.

Comment: Look at the new feature [`Sequence Number`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff878091.aspx)

Comment: @M.Ali If I'm reading the documentation correctly, using a `Sequence Number` would mean I can no longer control the FK constraint in the DB layer. I would rather not pawn that responsibility off on the app layer...

Comment: maybe try a trigger to update the previous_id?